# how can I override a JS function in Odoo 11?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

I want to completely override this function from Mail module, Activity.js

```
_onMarkActivityDone: function (event) {

    console.log("start new:::::::::::")
    event.preventDefault();

        }).popover('show');
    }
}
```

Comment: `ContainerObj._onMarkActivityDone: ()=>{}`

Comment: @Jai like this ?      ---- ' odoo.define('odoo_mark_as_done_require', function (require) {
    "use strict";
    ContainerObj._onMarkActivityDone: ()=>{
     event.preventDefault();
        
        var activity_id = $popover_el.data('activity-id');
        var previous_activity_type_id = $popover_el.data('previous-activity-type-id');
    }
    });'